SSRS Chart paged Legend Key only appears first time
I have a report in SSRS (created in VS), it has a Chart with series as bars.
The chart is paged on groupings.
However, the legend only shows the keys which appear on the current page when that key hasn't appeared on a previous page.
Is there a way to make all the keys for which there is series data on the current page appear in the legend on that page - regardless of whether it appeared in any previous pages?
If this is not possible, alternatively would it be possible to make all the keys appear on the Legend on the first page or on every page?
Thanks.
